# Handle Enter Key for search and login page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, search, authentication, enter

I have an ASP.Net 3.5 in VB.Net page that uses a master-page and has several pages it uses to display content.  On the master-page their is a search text-box for the site so that shows up on all the pages.  Their is also a login page screen to get to a members account.

The issue is:  When you are on a content page I would like when a user puts something in to search for and presses enter it will process the search request.

But....

If you are on the login page I would like to disable enter key for the search and if the user presses enter on the login page to process the login request.

Is their an easy way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your form in an [asp:panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.aspx) and set the [DefaultButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx) to be the button of the form you want to submit when enter is pressed

```
<asp:Panel DefaultButton="btnSubmit" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"/>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Password" TextMode="Password" runat="server"/>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Sign In" runat="server"/>
</asp:Panel>
```

Note: asp:panel creates a div